# Vivado, Zynq, BRAM Controller, Narrow AXI burst option

Tags: xilinx, vivado, zynq, axi4

Consider a simple system with PS (Processor system) with enabled AXI3 Master, connected to AXI4 Interconnect connected to BRAM Controller that has access to BRAM memory.

[image: System Block Diagram]

What is the meaning of AXI Narrow Bursts? How do i define or consider what is narrow burst? Can i control whether I want a narrow burst or not?

[image: BRAM Controller Options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrow burst allows transfer of data smaller than the data bus width.  The main use use to allow slave devices of differing bus widths, or requests of a smaller width, to to communicate with the master.

Please see [AXI4 (Lite) Narrow Burst vs. Unaligned Burst Clarification/Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377615/axi4-lite-narrow-burst-vs-unaligned-burst-clarification-compatibility) The accepted answer gives a good description.

Comment: Here is another related question with a bounty: [AXI Protocol, difference between secure and non-secure transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931678/axi-protocol-difference-between-secure-and-non-secure-transactions) maybe you have an answer here too.

Comment: @Strom thank you. It makes a lot of sense. And also for answering the other question.

Comment: @Paebbels thank you for tracking these questions and getting the other question answered as well